# Javafx Webview change text field content

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I am trying to find and element (input text field) on a web page in WebView and then put some text inside it.

So far I got to the part where I can find the element on a page , but I cant figure out how to manupilate with it, like put some text inside it.

The code bellow puts text inside Element but on the page in webview nothing changes.

```
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
Element form1 = doc.getElementById("SPSENDERINFORMATIONADD1");
form1.setTextContent("Some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive got it 
I used JavaScript
  webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"SPSENDERINFORMATIONADD1\").value='SomeText'");